# Look for SQL value in result set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In our database schema, the ItemID is typically included in the ItemValue column, but it's padded with information (A URL specifically). I am trying to find a way to query our database and look for places where the ItemID is not contained in the ItemValue column.

Here is the gist of what I am trying to do, replace  with the ItemValue value for that row.

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemValue
 FROM SomeTable
WHERE Deleted = 0
 AND ItemID NOT LIKE '%<ITEMVALUE>%'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be case-insensitive, e.g. if your ItemID can be alphanumeric, introduce a `lower()` function:

```
SELECT ItemID,
       ItemValue
  FROM SomeTable
 WHERE Deleted = 0
   AND lower(ItemID) NOT LIKE '%'|| lower(ITEMVALUE) ||'%';
```

Or:

```
SELECT ItemID,
       ItemValue
  FROM SomeTable
 WHERE Deleted = 0
   AND instr(lower(itemvalue), lower(ItemID)) = 0;
```

I'm not sure which of these is more performant, but both work.

If you don't care about uppercase or lowercase, e.g. if the ID is numeric, you can just remove the `lower()` functions.